# Run ExplainerDashboard inside a streamlit application

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization, streamlit

I want to run the ExplainerDashboard inside a Streamlit application. Is there a way I can do that? I have tried all modes of ExplainerDashboard `run()` function but it still isn't working for me.

Here is what I have done so far but it doesn't work.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def app():
    
    st.title("This is the machine learning page")
    st.markdown("redirect to my [app](https://github.com/prakharrathi25/data-storyteller/blob/main/app.py)")


    st.write("This is an example of a Streamlit app - machine learning")
    
    # show the same data in the machine learning page 
    data = pd.read_csv('data/iris.csv')
    st.dataframe(data)

    # Divide X and y 
    X = data[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
    y = data['E']

    # Convert y to labels 
    y = y.map({'Iris-setosa': 0, 'Iris-versicolor': 1, 'Iris-virginica': 2})

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8)

    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    st.write(model) # the code only runs till here

    explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test)
    ExplainerDashboard(explainer).run(mode='external')

    st.markdown("Check out the [explainer dashboard](http://192.168.1.3:8050/)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the dashboard normally, and run streamlit loading the url of dashboard as [iframe in streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/1.7.0/library/components/components-api#stiframe) app.

1. run dashboard
2. Get dashboard local url
3. run streamlit

#### Streamlit code

```py
def app():
    """
    Set appearance to wide mode.
    """
    st.title("This is the machine learning page")

    dashboardurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/'
    st.components.v1.iframe(dashboardurl, width=None, height=900, scrolling=True)
```

#### Image

[image]